# Prevent lookup field from being updated if status = complete or in transit

Tags: validation, validation-rule, configuration

Hello i have a requirement where i need to prevent editing on the lookup field "Consignment Event" lookup field if Picklist "Status" = In Transit or Complete

Here is what i got so far.

```
AND ( 
ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Closed / Complete'), 

ISPICKVAL(Status__c ,'In Transit'), 

OR( 

ISCHANGED (Consignment_Event__c)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the validation rule in below format : -

```
AND ( 
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Closed / Complete'), 
        ISPICKVAL(Status__c ,'In Transit')
    ), 
    ISCHANGED (Consignment_Event__c)
    )
```

you want to check Status__c with either or condition, So those  will put in or condition.